# How the java heap allocation for eden and other generation affects the Garbage collection and Performance?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I want to know how different values set for the **Xmx, Xms, Xmn** and **Xss** Affects the Garbage collection and Performance?

On basis of what parameters we can decide the optimum values for these parameters?

What are the **tools** available for the **monitoring** and **analyzing** the same?

Comment: A really valuable book I would recommend you on this topic is "Java Performance" Chapter 7 "Tuning the JVM, Step by Step" http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137001040/tuning-the-jvm-step-by-step/ch07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a detailed description http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing is one of the better resources to follow .

As far as the tools are concerned , apart from the default java tools like Hprof ,hat ,visualvm and Jconsole . Other commercial ones also exist like Appdynamics , yourkit , jprofiler , dynatrace ,newrelic ,etc .

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best thing is to performance test you application under realistic load.

Generally speaking these parameters are reasonably optimal if you leave them alone.  You should only set them if you know doing so improves performance.  To know it improves performance you should have a load test which demonstrates that performance is better with that setting.
(Anything else is just guess work)

Answer (score 0):

So first some helpful link :

1. [GC tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)
2. [Diagnosing a Garbage Collection problem](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/example-141412.html)
3. [Monitoring](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/)
4. [GC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html)

For monitoring I'm used to `Netbeans Profiler`.

You can also set some VM option to print GC activity with (for example) :

> -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

or

> -agentlib:hprof=heap=all

Finally you can monitor your app using [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html).

There is a lot of other monitoring tools, choose yours!